# Core data entities sharing same property?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nstableview, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've a core data entity called Record with a property called sentence of type NSString and another created of type NSDate. This is tied to an NSTableView through a NSArrayController that's connected to my local NSManagedObjectContext.

Now, every time I create a new instance of Record, all existing instances of Record end up with the same text in sentence but created remains with the correct value. What's the best way to debug this? How can I see what's happening to Record?

Answer (score 0):

Add an observer for your context:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourDebugMethod) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:yourContext];
```

Then, in `yourDebugMethod` you can breakpoint for changes to your record objects and maybe this will help you find the issue.